# Implementing a user specific editable calendar

Tags: html, database, wordpress, calendar

I have been tasked with creating a calendar that my users have the ability to edit. I require it to be created with a template built in on creation. They will then be able to adjust and correct the suggested template to fit their needs.

I have searched for some answers to this and there are too many ways for me to choose from.

Am I allowed to create a discussion so people can share the experiences & complications they have had when implementing such a calendar?

If you can help me with code bases and save everyone who is in a similar situation some pains then bonus!

Thanks coders, Jason.

Comment: Did you think of using a plugin for this ? Like The Event Calendar or Event Manager ? What's the purpose of your client's calendar ?

Comment: A plug in was the first place I looked and seems like the best way but I still thought to get some opinions, maybe a wizard would bestow upon me some genius code that would add more custom features. I intend on suggesting actions to the user for certain days - in the example of a blog website - their calendar would have 'Monday - publish a new post', 'Tuesday - post on social', 'Wednesday - change featured blogs on homepage'... but they would be able to see this and go through the calendar editing it to their requirements.

Comment: It may even be used for them to see but we would edit it and they can see how we plan to keep their blog up to date and when they can expect changes / when to have content across to us by. Thanks for the response

Comment: @AlexVand - tagging you

Comment: So maybe a calendar on the admin dashboard could be good for you ? So when your client logs into the admin, he could see it immediatly ?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of creating a subdomain call it calendar.website.com then installing a plug in on there that has a calendar functionality. The only functionality needed is for it to be unique to each user. Have the ability to have a template calendar in place with our recommended dates / plans that they have the ability to edit. Then have the ability to narrow down what shows in the calendar by categorising the dates / plans (potentially colour coded would be nice). @AlexVand